# Login Failed Error for the registered user in Android using Parse

Tags: android, authentication, parse-platform

I have already registered an user using the Parse registration process for parse.com.

```
ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
    user.setUsername(mEtUname.getText().toString());
    user.setPassword(mEtPwd.getText().toString());
    user.setEmail(mEtEmail.getText().toString());

    // other fields can be set just like with ParseObject
    user.put("phone", "xxxxxxxxxx");

    user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {

    @Override
    public void done(com.parse.ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (e == null) {
              // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
            Log.d("Testing", "registration  successful ");
            Toast.makeText(RegistrationScreen.this, "I am registered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
              // Sign up didn't succeed. Look at the ParseException
              // to figure out what went wrong
                Log.d("Testing", "registration not successful "+e.getMessage());
            }
    }
    });
}
```

After registration user is showing on the parse user list on browser on the Parse website. Now i am trying to login the user using the below code:

```
ParseUser.logInInBackground(username, pwd, new LogInCallback() {

        @Override
        public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (user != null) {
                Log.d("Testing", "I am logged in");
            } else {
                // Signup failed. Look at the ParseException to see what
                // happened.
                switch (e.getCode()) {
                case ParseException.USERNAME_TAKEN:
                    Log.d("Testing","Sorry, this username has already been taken.");
                    break;
                case ParseException.USERNAME_MISSING:
                    Log.d("Testing","Sorry, you must supply a username to register.");
                    break;
                case ParseException.PASSWORD_MISSING:
                    Log.d("Testing","Sorry, you must supply a password to register.");
                    break;
                case ParseException.OBJECT_NOT_FOUND:
                    Log.d("Testing","Sorry, those credentials were invalid.");
                    break;
                case ParseException.CONNECTION_FAILED:
                    Log.d("Testing","Internet connection was not found. Please see your connection settings.");
                    break;
                default:
                    Log.d("Testing",e.getLocalizedMessage());
                    break;
                }
```

But every time it is saying "sorry. log in failed invalid login credentials". I have checked first logout the user and then login. But result is same.

Can anyone please help.

Thanks, Arindam

Comment: Just make sure I understand. After sign up you go to sing in? Once you did the sing up you user is already logged in, so there is no need for singing  in again. ParseUser.getCurrentUser(); should give you the user you just signed up.

Comment: Now suppose i logged out and i am trying to sign in. In that case it should logged in right? But in this case also it is not going through.

Comment: Maybe to use this check before: ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
if (currentUser != null) {
  // do stuff with the user
} else {
  // show the signup or login screen
}